# How to get the message notification in admin panel once the order placed from the customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, adminnotification

How to receive the message notification in admin panel once the order placed from the customer?

As of now, admin is receiving email but I want to show the notification also in admin panel like the following:

[image]

Comment: like push notification in admin panel am i right

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little Magento extension,its called Inchoo_AdminOrderNotifier. The whole idea behind the extension was to fulfill the request where you as a merchant wish to have your store personnel instantly notified when customer places an order on your store.

You can download on following Link.

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-admin-order-notifier/

https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_AdminOrderNotifier

I hope it's helpful for you.